# ¿Cómo cargo una imagen a objeto Json y llamarla en Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

cómo puedo colocar una imagen en un objeto Json y que se muestre cuando Ajax llama este objeto, estaba leyendo que los objetos Json son solo string, entonces no sé si es posible,

puse mi objeto así

```
{
     "name": "Chocolate Cherry Cola",
     "recipe": "The domestic rebel",
     "imgPath": "images/logo.jpg"

    },
```

y este es mi ajax

```
 $.ajax({

 type: "GET",
 url: "js/cupcakes.json ",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType:'json',

 success: function(result)
 {
 console.log(result);
 var output="<table class='table'><thead><tr><th><h3> Name</h3></th><th><h3>Recipe by</h3> </th><th><h3>URL</h3></th></tr></thead></tbody>";
 for (var i in result)
 {
 output+="<tr><td>" + result[i].name + "</td><td>" + result[i].recipe + "</td><td>" + "<img src='images/'" + result[i].map + "</td></tr>";
 }
 output+="</tbody></table>";

 displayCakes.html(output);
 $("table").addClass("table");
 }
```

¿es necesario convertirla?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solo puede contestarte a parte de la pregunta, para poder cargar una imagen en un objeto json, primero tienes que pasarla a cadena, en php puedes hacerlo con la función base64_decode / base64_encode esta funcion es precisamente para poder convertir datos binarios que no se pueden poner directamente en una cadena a caracteres que si se pueden poner en una cadena, la funcion que decodifica, los devuelve al estado binario original.
Espero que te sirva de algo.

Comment: Eso era antiguamente, ahora se soporta [blobs](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob-section)

Comment: @Jauma, en lugar de colocar los bytes de las imágenes en un json, es mucho mas sencillo agregar las etiquetas `img` con Javascript y eso hará que las imágenes se carguen solas. Eso es lo que hace el codigo que publicó el que hizo la pregunta. Además se pueden dejar ocultas mientras cargan.

Comment: pero como está el codigo no muestra las imágenes